# How to authorize Chrome Extension using a token?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a service that has authorization methods using a key (made for a mobile application).
How can I authorize a Chome Extension using key authorization?
I see that many extensions do a redirect to their site for authorization. But I can’t figure out how to organize authorization in my extension.

I can make username and password fields in the extension. But I think this is not the best way to solve it.

Comment: It's my understanding an extension itself (as in the installed instance) isn't something that gets authorization... but it's the users session within the extension that you want to authorize. Any authorization in the user experience of the extension would occur just like with any other webpage (and through extension design you can choose to show this state to the user in different ways... like in a pop-up). After authorization, presumably you'd store a token client-side in some form (a cookie), and you'd pass it with all your subsequent server requests occurring in the extension experience.